# 'size_t' vs 'container::size_type'

Tags: c++, size-type, container-data-type

Is there is a difference between `size_t` and `container::size_type`?

What I understand is `size_t` is more generic and can be used for any `size_type`s.

But is `container::size_type` optimized for specific kinds of containers?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The standard containers define `size_type` as a typedef to `Allocator::size_type` (Allocator is a template parameter), which for `std::allocator<T>::size_type` is **typically** defined to be `size_t` (or a compatible type). So for the standard case, they are the same.

However, if you use a custom allocator a different underlying type could be used. So `container::size_type` is preferable for maximum generality.

Comment: Can you clarify this answer? I have looked back at the draft standards as far back as `N1804` and I don't see any relationship between `Allocator::size_type` and `size_type`. A quick glance at libstdc++ does not show anything similar to this either.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, So this answer is slightly outdated, but to maximize portability I think the advice is still sound: C++03 specified "Table 32: size_type: a type that can represent the size of the largest object in the allocation model." At the time, `size_t` was the bet practical implementation of those constraints. However, in C++11, it is now defined essentially as: `std::make_unsigned<X::difference_type>::type` by default. Which in practice, will probably be the same or compatible with `size_t`.

Comment: CARE  the answer is incorrect....
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849678/c-for-loop-size-type-vs-size-t
TL:DR: allocators size_type need to be size_t and in C++17 size_type will be deprecated as is.

Comment: @user3063349 I see nothing in that page, nor in the C++ 2017 Standard (23.10.8), to hint at `size_type` deprecation. What gives?

Comment: @Marc.2377 see https://omegaup.com/docs/cpp/en/cpp/memory/allocator.html

Answer (score 50):

- `size_t` is defined as the type used for the size of an object and is **platform dependent**.
- `container::size_type` is the type that is used for the number of elements in the container and is **container dependent**.

All `std` containers use `size_t` as the `size_type`, but each independent library vendor chooses a type that it finds appropriate for its container.

If you look at [qt](/questions/tagged/qt), you'll find that the `size_type` of Qt containers is version dependent. In Qt3 it was `unsigned int` and in Qt4 it was changed to `int`.

Comment: I find it a bit odd to have the size of something expressed as an int. Could we ever have a negative size for a container?

Comment: @MihaiTodor: it's not unusual for people to use signed types for everything, I guess Qt is following suit. The reason is that mixed operations (in particular comparisons) are such a disaster area that many people would rather avoiding using unsigned types for numbers, than have to deal with and/or avoid mixed ops. Just because unsigned types can't express negative numbers, doesn't mean you *have* to use them for numbers that can't be negative :-) I confess I'm surprised it's `int` rather than `ssize_t`, `int` is kind of small.

Comment: "All std containers use size_t as the size_type" very very false and misleading.
Yes, they USUALLY do ( at least all my compilers did that way ) but the C++ language reference doesen't state, that it need to be similar for all stl container!! so care

Comment: I think it is worth noting that [A type whose size cannot be represented by std::size_t is ill-formed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)

Answer (score 9):

For `std::[w]string`, `std::[w]string::size_type` is equal to `std::allocator<T>::size_type`, which is equal to the `std::size_t`. For other containers, it's some implementation defined unsigned integer type.

Sometimes it's useful to have the exact type, so for example one knows where the type wraps around to (like, to `UINT_MAX`) so that one can make use of that. Or for templates, where you really need to pass two identical types to function/class templates.

Often i find i use `size_t` for brevity or iterators anyway. In generic code, since you generally don't know with what container instance your template is used and what size those containers have, you will have to use the `Container::size_type` typedef if you need to store the containers size.