# size_t vs int in C++ and/or C

Tags: c++, c, size-type

Why is it that in C++ containers, it returns a `size_type` rather than an `int`? If we're creating our own structures, should we also be encouraged to use `size_type`?

Comment: There is a size_t and size_type comparison at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/sizet-vs-containersizetype

Comment: @PCBEEF, you had it right the first time, basic_string::size returns size_type not size_t. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s50w4ze4.aspx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In general, `size_t` should be used whenever you are measuring the size of something. It is really strange that `size_t` is only required to represent between 0 and `SIZE_MAX` bytes and `SIZE_MAX` is only required to be 65,535...

The other interesting constraints from the C++ and C Standards are:

- the return type of `sizeof()` is `size_t` and it is an *unsigned integer*
- `operator new()` takes the number of bytes to allocate as a `size_t` parameter
- `size_t` is defined in `<cstddef>`
- `SIZE_MAX` is defined in `<limits.h>` in C99 but not mentioned in C++98?!
- `size_t` is not included in the list of *fundamental integer types* so I have always assumed that `size_t` is a type alias for one of the fundamental types: `char`, `short int`, `int`, and `long int`.

If you are counting bytes, then you should definitely be using `size_t`. If you are counting the number of elements, then you should probably use `size_t` since this seems to be what C++ has been using. In any case, you don't want to use `int` - at the very least use `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` if you are using TR1. Or... even better... `typedef` whatever you end up using to `size_type` or just include `<cstddef>` and use `std::size_t`.

Comment: size_t is not only required to go up to 64k, it's also required to be able to represent the size of any object (in the C standard, I think, so maybe the C++ standard doesn't mention it). Pretty much any compiler is going to have to make it the same size as a pointer. Not quite as strange as it looks.

Comment: Yes, it is required to represent the size of any single object allocation in memory. It isn't required to represent the maximum number of objects, just the number of bytes consumed by the largest representable object. Comparing the range of size_t with addressable memory isn't really a valid comparison unless you can allocate the entire range of addressable memory in a single object.

Comment: Hence "pretty much any compiler". Now that we mostly have unsegmented memory architectures, and a desire to mmap large files, and most compilers implement intptr_t (from C99) or similar, there's not much mileage in artificially limiting the size of an object to a smaller integer type than can span the address space. So that's why I don't think it's surprising that C++ implementations use size_t for size_type. The reason the 64k SIZE_MAX minimum is so low is probably just to support 16bit architectures: you'd not expect a 32bit+ compiler to actually do that.

Answer (score 10):

A few reasons might be:

- The type (size_t) can be defined as the largest unsigned integer on that platform. For example, it might be defined as a 32 bit integer or a 64 bit integer or something else altogether that's capable of storing unsigned values of a great length
- To make it clear when reading a program that the value is a size and not just a "regular" int

If you're writing an app that's just for you and/or throwaway, you're probably fine to use a basic int. If you're writing a library or something substantial, size_t is probably a better way to go.

Comment: imagine a simple freshly booted 64 bits OS with no bloatware, you can do `new char[6 gigs]` and it will work if you have enough RAM or swap space. Now, how do you manage that with an int ? this is the reason behind `size_t`.

Answer (score 8):

Some of the answers are more complicated than necessary.  A size_t is an unsigned integer type that is guaranteed to be big enough to store the size in bytes of any object in memory.  In practice, it is always the same size as the pointer type.  On 32 bit systems it is 32 bits. On 64 bit systems it is 64 bits.

Comment: For fun: I recall a potential counter-example to same size pointer/size_t.  In the DOS 16-bit segment:16-bit offset scheme.  The pointer was then 32 bits.  The size_t was limited to 16 bits.  Hope such schemes do not occur again.

Comment: That's actually correct.  The segment/offset really wasn't a "pointer" in the C sense as you couldn't do arithmetic on it naturally (though compilers were pretty good about hiding this with generated code in "huge" mode).  The biggest single thing you could address via offsets was indeed 65536 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

All containers in the stl have various typedefs. For example, `value_type` is the element type, and `size_type` is the number stored type. In this way the containers are completely generic based on platform and implementation.

If you are creating your own containers, you should use `size_type` too. Typically this is done

```
typedef std::size_t size_type;
```

If you want a container's size, you should write

```
typedef vector<int> ints;
ints v;
v.push_back(4);
ints::size_type s = v.size();
```

What's nice is that if later you want to use a list, just change the typedef to

```
typedef list<int> ints;
```

And it will still work!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean "size_t" -- this is a way of indicating an unsigned integer (an integer that can only be positive, never negative) -- it makes sense for containers' sizes since you can't have an array with a size of -7. I wouldn't say that you have to use size_t but it does indicate to others using your code "This number here is always positive." It also gives you a greater range of positive numbers, but that is likely to be unimportant unless you have some very big containers.

Comment: size_t and size_type (although they have commonly same value) are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a language that could be implemented on different hardware architectures and platforms. As time has gone by it has supported 16-, 32-, and 64-bit architecture, and likely others in the future. `size_type` and other type aliases are ways for libraries to insulate the programmers/code from implementation details.

Assuming the `size_type` uses 32 bits on 32-bit machines and 64 bits on 64-bit machines, the same source code likely would work better if you've used size_type where needed. In most cases you could assume it would be the same as `unsigned int`, but it's not guaranteed.

[`size_type`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Container.html) is used to express capacities of STL containers like [`std::vector`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html) whereas `size_t` is used to express byte size of an object in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

ints are not guaranteed to be 4 bytes in the specification, so they are not reliable. Yes, size_type would be preferred over ints

Comment: Are size_t's guaranteed to be any particular size?

Comment: Strangely enough they are only required to be able to represent values between 0 and 65,535. The relevant clause in the Standard is 7.18.3 in C99. The actual limitation is between 0 and SIZE_MAX as defined in <limits.h>

Comment: @DShawley int is only guaranteed to be able to represent up to 32,767. So I'm not sure what your point is.

Answer (score 0):

`size_t` is unsigned, so even if they're both 32 bits it doesn't mean quite the same thing as an unqualified int.  I'm not sure why they added the type, but on many platforms today `sizeof (size_t) == sizeof (int) == sizeof (long)`, so which type you choose is up to you.  Note that those relations aren't guaranteed by the standard and are rapidly becoming out of date as 64 bit platforms move in.

For your own code, if you need to represent something that is a "size" conceptually and can never be negative, `size_t` would be a fine choice.

Answer (score -5):

```
void f1(size_t n) {
    if (n <= myVector.size()) { assert(false); }
    size_t n1 = n - myVector.size(); // bug! myVector.size() can be > n       
    do_stuff_n_times(n1);
}

void f2(int n) {
    int n1 = n - static_cast<int>(myVector.size());
    assert(n1 >= 0);
    do_stuff_n_times(n1);
}
```

f1() and f2() both have the same bug, but detecting the problem in f2() is easier. For more complex code, unsigned integer arithmetic bugs are not as easy to identify.

Personally I use signed int for all my sizes unless unsigned int should be used. I have never run into situation where my size won't fit into a 32 bit signed integer. I will probably use 64 bit signed integers before I use unsigned 32 bit integers.

The problem with using signed integers for size is a lot of `static_cast` from `size_t` to `int` in your code.

Comment: This isn't actually a very good point as an `assert(n >= myVector.size()) ;` detects the bug flawlessly.