# How to reverse a array of chars and then store the reversed array of char to another array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, reverse

I have been working on this very simple question. I am trying to reverse a array of chars and then store this reversed array of chars into another array using c language. Here is my code, I can not figure out what is the problem of my code. I really do not understand why when I try to print out my stcp which is the array with the reversed string, there is nothing show up on the screen. Please advice, any help would be really appreciate.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char st[100];
    scanf("%s", st);
    int count = 0;
    while(st[count] != '\0'){
        count++;
    }

    //printf("%s", st);
    char stcp[100];
    int i, j = 0;
    for(i = count-1; i >= 0; i--){
        st[i] = stcp[j];
        j++;
    }

    puts(stcp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's `C`, then you shouldnt' tag your question as `C++`, since in `C++`, all you have to do is call `std::reverse`.

Comment: `st[i] = stcp[j];` --> `stcp[j] = st[i];` .. `stcp[j] = 0;`

Comment: Minor: better to use `size_t count` than `int count`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/994357/2410359

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean the following

```
char stcp[100];
int i = count, j = 0;

while ( i != 0 ) stcp[j++] = st[--i];
stcp[j] = '\0';
```

As for your original code then you have to exchange operands in this statement

```
   st[i] = stcp[j];
```

and string `stcp` must be appended with the terminating zero.

Take into account that function main should be defined in C like

```
int main( void )
```

As for me I would declare variables `count`, `i`, and `j` as having type `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch this line:

```
st[i] = stcp[j];
```

To this:

```
stcp[j] = st[i];
```