# array not storing the address of structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures, structure

I am trying to implement graph using adjacency list ,according to my knowledge that i have learnt so far if i created variable `array` pointer to `struct adjlistnode` of size `v*sizeof(struct adjlistnode)` thin i can store the addresses of v `struct adjlistnode` type node in each index of array

Means that each index of array will point to the node of type `struct adjlistnode`  but when i am assigning `G->array[i]=NULL` it gives me error

`||=== Build: Debug in teeest (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Mahi\Desktop\DATA STR\teeest\main.c||In function 'creategraph':|
C:\Users\Mahi\Desktop\DATA STR\teeest\main.c|59|error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct adjlistnode' from type 'void *'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|`

> why i am not able to assign NULL to index of array

what should i do if i want to access adjacency list like using `G->array[i]`=first node address   adjacent to `i`th vertex of graph and later i will add another node if  needed

```
struct adjlistnode{
    int dest;
    struct adjlistnode* next;
};
struct graph{
   int V;
   struct adjlistnode* array;
};
struct adjlistnode* getnewnode(int dest){
   struct adjlistnode* newnode =(struct adjlistnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct adjlistnode));
   newnode->dest=dest;
   newnode->next=NULL;
   return newnode;
}
struct graph* creategraph(int v){
   struct graph* G=(struct graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
   G->V=v;
   G->array=(struct adjlistnode*)malloc(v*sizeof(struct adjlistnode));

   for(int i=0;i<v;i++){
      G->array[i] =NULL;
   }
   return G;

}
```

Comment: becasue only pointers can be `NULL`. Your `G->array` is not an array of pointers

Comment: At least in C all these casts are useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`G->array` is of type `struct adjlistnode *`

But

`G->array[i]` is of type `struct adjlistnode`.

Thus you cannot assign `NULL` (of type `void *`) to `G->array[i]` of type `struct adjlistnode`

You should probably have to define `array` in the `struct graph` as *pointer to pointer*

```
struct graph{
   int V;
   struct adjlistnode** array;
};
```

and then the following should work for you

```
struct graph* creategraph(int v){
   struct graph* G=malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
   G->V=v;
   G->array=malloc(v*sizeof(struct adjlistnode*));

   for(int i=0;i<v;i++){
      G->array[i] =NULL;
   }
   return G;

}
```

** *Note1* (as also mentioned by @alk in the comments) that in C, at least since C89 standard, `malloc` returns `void *`. `void *` can be assigned to any other pointer type (and visa versa), thus casting the return value of `malloc` is not required.

** *Note2* (also noted by @alk) that `malloc` signature is defined with the parameter of type `size_t` and not `int` so better to modify the code a little and use the proper type ( Read [comparing int with size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642067/5218277) and [size_t vs int in C++ and/or C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994288/size-t-vs-int-in-c-and-or-c) for more info)

Comment: Nitpicking again: All those `int`s should be `size_t`s.

Comment: @alk, I agree that it would be the most correct and potentially prevent `signed vs unsigned` bugs but it is rather related to *code review* area than to the question itself. But I don't mind to add another note.

Comment: if i want to pass `v`as  `size_t` then is there any need to change the `int` to `size_t` in 
my structures

Comment: @david12345 yes, better to be aligned with the proper type. There is no reason for `v` ever be negative

Answer (score 1):

`array` is a (single) pointer to `struct adjlistnode`. So it can be set to NULL.

```
 G->array = NULL; //is okay
```

But it is not an array of pointers, so you cannot access the elements of the array and they cannot be set to NULL as well.

For dynamic allocation, you should do this:

```
struct graph{
   int V;
   struct adjlistnode** array;
};
struct graph* creategraph(int v){
   struct graph* G = malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
   G->V = v;   
   G->array = malloc(v * sizeof(struct adjlistnode*)); //allocation for an array of v pointers 

   for(int i = 0; i < v; i++){    
      G->array[i] = NULL;
   }
   return G;
}
```

As suggested by @alk, it is better if you pass `v` as `size_t` instead of `int`, as `malloc` takes `size_t`.

Comment: Like this: `struct adjlistnode* array[10];`

Comment: ok sir i got it but if i want to make it dynamically in my above case
you can tell me in one line please

Comment: Updated the answer for dynamic allocation. Check it out.

Comment: Nitpicking: All those `int`s should be `size_t`s.

Comment: @alk: Updated based on your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: if i want to pass `v`as  `size_t` in creategraph then is there any need to change the `int` to `size_t` in 
my structures or where should i change `int` to `size_t` in my structures

Comment: Yes. It is a good practice to use the types as required by the library functions.

Comment: You will have to include stdlib.h to use size_t

Answer (score 1):

`G->array[i]` returns `*(array + i * sizeof(struct adjlistnode))` as if `array` was `struct adjlistnode array[]`.

What you do is store v objects of `struct`, but you try to initialize them with NULL, like you would a pointer.

What you probably want is

```
struct graph{
   int V;
   struct adjlistnode** array;
};

[...]

G->array=(struct adjlistnode**)malloc(v*sizeof(struct adjlistnode*));
```

That would make `array` a pointer to an array of pointers.

Then `G->array[i]` would return a `struct adjlistnode*` pointer to an object of struct, that you can then initialize with your `getnewnode()`.

Comment: At least in C all these casts are useless.