# Modulo arithmetic with signed integers undefined behavior in c?

Tags: c, unsigned, undefined-behavior, signed

Having read all answers and comments in [Should you always use 'int' for numbers in C, even if they are non-negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259413/should-you-always-use-int-for-numbers-in-c-even-if-they-are-non-negative/15937117#15937117) I'm still not sure what to do in the following situation.

Two remote devices are counting events at their respective location. They regularly report the counter readings to a PC where a feedback algorithm somehow keeps the difference of the counter readings within bounds. The sequences of events are endless so that the readings are reported modulo 2^n. For modulo arithmetic unsigned integers are suggested. The difference, however, may well become negative. Casting the readings to signed integers before calculating the difference works fine on the platform I tested it on (that is, I get the differences modulo 2^n with values small in magnitude). Declaring the readings as signed already in the interface yields elegant code. However, the code shall be portable. Shall I take the U.B. warning seriously?

Comment: One option to consider: if the values from the counters are 16-bit unsigned numbers, you could arrange to read them into 32-bit signed numbers.  Or if they're 32-bit, you could read them into 64-bit numbers.  Then the differences are defined, and negatives will be negative, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler negatives will be negative, but their modular residues will stay undefined.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thank you for this idea. Seems to be faster and more legible than solutions based on branching.

Comment: @Jan: Modular residues are unambiguous as I know that the magnitude of the difference is small.

Comment: Thinking about both comments I found another solution: Calculating the difference with unsigned numbers, addition of 2^(n-2) to it, cast to signed (result is safely in the positive range), subtraction of 2^(n-2). This shall be well-defined and is hopefully optimized by the compiler to just taking the difference on all existing platforms.

Comment: @Rainald62 modular residues of negative values in mathematics are well defined. In C/C++, not so.

Comment: @Jan: I'm not asking for a residuum but for the well-defined difference. Modulo arithmetic comes only into play since the range of integer variables is limited in C/C++. Besides, in mathematics, there is no such thing as a modular residuum. … -13, -3, 7, 17 … are all "equal modulo 10".

Comment: What about this solution: `UpDownAminusB += (signed int)(ConterA - prevCounterA); prevCounterA = CounterA; UpDownAminusB -= (signed int)(ConterB - prevCounterB); prevCounterB = CounterB;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shall I take the U.B. warning seriously?

If you don't want your compiler or CPU play tricks on you, your code should be UB-free.