# size_t and memory allocation

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

There is such a type `std::size_t`. It may be used for describing the size of object as it is guaranteed to be able to express the maximum size of any object (so is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951519/when-should-i-use-stdsize-t)). But what does that mean? We actually have no objects in memory. So does that mean that this type can store an integer that represents the largest amount of memory we theoretically can use?

If I try to write something like

```
size_t maxSize = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();
new char[maxSize];
```

I will get an error because the total size of the array is limited to 0x7fffffff. Why?
Moreover, if I pass a nonconstant expression which is equal to `maxSize`, `std::bad_array_new_length` will be thrown. If I pass an expression which is less than `maxSize` but still greater than 0x7fffffff, `std::bad_alloc` will be thrown. I suppose that `std::bad_alloc` is thrown because of lack of memory, not because the size is greater than 0x7fffffff. Why does it happen so? I guess it is natural to throw a ***special*** exception if the size of memory we what to allocate is greater than 0x7fffffff (which is the max value for the const which is passed to new[] at compile time). And why is `std::bad_array_new_length` thrown only if I pass `maxSize`? Is this case special?

By the way, if I pass maxSize to the vector's constructor like this:

```
vector<char> vec(maxSize);
```

`std::bad_alloc` will be thrown, not `std::bad_array_new_length`. Does that mean that vector uses different allocator?

I'm trying to make an implementation of array on my own. Using unsigned int to store the size, capacity and indices is a bad approach. So is it a good idea to define some alias like this:

```
typedef std::size_t size_type;
```

and use `size_type` instead of `unsigned int`?

Comment: The maximum size of an object is not the same as the maximum amount of memory your implementation can allocate.

Comment: Typically, `std::vector<T>(size_t sz)` allocates a buffer that is `sizeof(T) * sz` bytes long and then uses placement new to construct the objects. This is versus using array new to allocate the memory and construct the objects. Also, `std::vector` is free to allocate room for more objects. When you erase objects from the vector, most likely the memory will not be released.

Comment: I noticed nine questions in that post. That indicates to me that your post is too broad.

Comment: If this is a 32 bit application on windows the largest allocation will be limited to around 1.2GB without using the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker setting. The reason is you have a 2GB address space + its fragmented.

Comment: @RustyX, error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes

Comment: ***new char[maxSize];*** Probably issues a compiler error because the compiler can easily determine the size at compile time.

Comment: ***I suppose that std::bad_alloc is thrown because of lack of memory*** Lack of a contiguous block of address space. `0x7fffffff` +1 is the total amount of address space allocated to a 32 bit program under windows that is not using LARGEADDRESSAWARE.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, I think that's the case. So the value I pass to new[] operator is limited to the size of memory which is allocated to the program

Comment: There are a lot of different questions here.  It's not clear what the main question is, and some of them might lead to speculation.  So take your pick, too broad, unclear, and primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the process involved in the creation of an object of dynamic storage duration.

To make short, when the program executes a *new expression* as : `new char[size]`:

1. It checks that `s=size*sizeof(char)+x` is a valid size (implementation defined 0x7fffffff, which depends on the ABI)(x=0 on most platform if you create array of trivially destructible type). If the size is invalid, it throws `bad_array_new_lenght`, otherwise,
2. It calls the allocation function `::operator new(s)`. This function first parameter is `std::size_t`, this is why `std::size_t` must be large enough to create an object (an array is an object) of any size.
3. This allocation function asks the system to reserve a region of storage of size `s`. If the system succeeds to reserve this space it returns a pointer to the beginning of the storage region. Otherwise it calls a *new handler* and retry allocation, but if it fails once again, it throws  `bad_alloc`
4. If allocation succeed, it *default initializes* (in this case) the `size` `char` (no-op) on the allocated storage, and it may also store the size of the array on this allocated storage (the reason to be of the added `x`) (This is used when executing a *delete expression* in order to know hown many destructors must be called. If the destructor is trivial, this is not necessary).

You will find all the details in the c++ standard (§6.7.4 [basic.stc.dynamic], §8.3 [expr.new], §8.4 [expr.delete], §21.6 [support.dynamic]).

And for the last question, you may consider using a *signed* type for the index and for the object size. Even if object size or index should not be negative, the standard imposes that unsigned arithmetic followes modulo-arithmetic which limits seriously optimization. Moreover unsigned integer type arithmetic and comparison are frequent subjects of bugs. `std::size_t` is unsigned for compatibility reason, it was choosen to be unsigned because prehistoric machine were short in bits! (16 bits or less!)