# Do not use array subscript when the index is not an integer constant expression; use gsl::at() instead

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines, resharper-c++

I was trying to create some example code in Microsoft Visual Studio which looks like that

```
int main()
{
    const size_t size = 10;
    int arr[size];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        arr[i] = i;

    return 0;
}
```

Now JetBrains ResharperC++ emits the following warning in line `arr[i] = i;`

> [image]
>   Do not use array subscript when the index is not an integer constant expression; use gsl::at() instead

I fail to understand what I this means and how to resolve this warning.

As this is a scheme I was using fairly often, I am a little concerned about the warning.

Could anyone advice or point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:** Changing the loop to:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    arr[i] = 0;
```

still produces the warning.

Comment: I think it complains that the index (i in your case) is not an int. depending on compiler and architecture, not using an int may have strange effects. so always better use an int, not a size_t, when indexing an array

Comment: @loonytune Changing all size_t to int does not fix the problem.

Comment: On another side note, u are assigning an size_t to an int[], which will go terribly wrong on every 64 bit architecture (because there sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(int)).

Comment: just for fun, can u try replacing the arr[i] = ... with *(arr + i) = ...?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951519/when-should-i-use-stdsize-t, you should use an unsigned int if you want to be on the safe side

Comment: @loonytune and the warning is gone... What dies that mean?

Comment: well, *(arr + i) is the same doing pointer arithmetics. maybe jetbrains complains that u are using array semantics with a variable index, although the array is fixed in size in your case. and by using pointer magic it doesnt detect that anymore. another experiment, try to replace the the declaration of int arr[size] with int[] arr = (int[]) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

Comment: This does not compile

Comment: This is the consequence of two C++ language design mistakes: 1) using exceptions to report logical bugs; 2) use unsigned integer for arrays size and subscripts. Just don't care two much about it, it will be fixed.

Comment: Alright! Thanks guys.

Comment: @Oliv Do you also happen to know what gsl::at() is?

Comment: @P i I suppose they have used the standard semantic. `an_array.at(index)` is equivalent to `if (index>=an_array.size()) throw a_logical_error{}; return an_array[index];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    arr[i] = something;
```

is dangerous.  You can't tell if `arr[i]` is going to go out of bounds of the array.  This is why the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines) suggest you use `gsl::at()` as it will do bounds checking to make sure you do not go out of bounds on the array.

This isn't the only solution though.  If you just need to iterator over the range you can use a range based for loop like

```
for (const auto& e : arr)
    //e is each element of the array and is not mutable here
```

or

```
for (auto& e : arr)
    //e is each element of the array and is mutable here
```

And for a case like yours where you need to fill the array you can use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) like

```
std::iota(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0);
```

and all of these are guaranteed to not go out of bounds.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to mute the linter, because it clearly cannot tell the difference. It will still be nagging at you when calling some code from a C library where for example a variable is declared as  double p[4][2]; how the hell does C++ want you to iterate over that?

Comment: @Mehdi If you need read write access `for (auto& row : p) for (auto& elem : row) { do_something_with_each_element; }`

Answer (score 3):

Its a warning that `arr[i]` doesn't do any bounds checking and that you should use `gsl::at(arr, i)` from https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL instead as it does bounds checking and is safer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for the warning is that `operator[]` does not boundary check, while `gsl::at()` could.

Since `size` is known in compile time, if the index was `constexpr`, you could get a warning, but if the value is determined in runtime you can't. In my opinion pretty unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an array element by index, without any bounds checking, is not considered a good practice. It is a direct memory access which is not safe and may cause [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

For an STL container like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), there's this [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) member function which performs the bounds-checking and is the recommended way to access elements.

You may ignore this warning for this trivial example. But, for non-trivial code, use `std::vector`. But, for C-style arrays, you may download and use `gsl::at()` and explore its other facilities as well.

---

References:
[C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines)
[GSL (Guideline Support Library)](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a (compiler) warning. It's one of the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) incorporated into a 3rd party IDE / analysis tool.

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning as `operator[]` doesn't check bound, contrary to `at`.
Whereas in your case, the code is correct, *"small"* change might break your loop (`int arr[2 * size];`)

There are several good alternatives using iterators (explicitly or implicitly) in your case:

```
const size_t size = 10;
int arr[size];

std::iota(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0);
```

or

```
int i = 0;
for (auto& e : arr) {
    e = i;
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
int array[] = {0, 1, 2};
for (auto element : array){
   if(element == 1){
   //.....
   }
}
```

Try above code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to need a more updated answer.

Rather than use a handwritten loop, it is suggested to use standard alogos. In this case `iota` does exactly what is needed: an auto incrementing assignment.

We also, for a static array should be using std::array instead of 'C' style arrays. But this would work just as well with vector, since iota takes runtime args.

```cpp
template<size_t SZ>
auto<int, SZ> CountInit()
{
    std::array<int, SZ> arr; // Note we only use SZ once

    std::iota(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0);
    return arr;
}
```

This can be done in a more compile time way using integer_sequence and some helpers:

```
// Note taken from : https://jgreitemann.github.io/2018/09/15/variadic-expansion-in-aggregate-initialization/
template <typename Container, int... I>
Container iota_impl(std::integer_sequence<int, I...>) {
    return {I...};
} 

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
auto iota_array() {
    using Sequence = std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>;
    return iota_impl<std::array<T, N>>(Sequence{});
}



auto foo2()
{
    return iota_array<int, 10>();
}

int goo2()
{
    auto x=foo2();
    return std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), 0);
}
```

According to https://godbolt.org/z/59hqqdEYj These are equivalent (as per c++20 iota is constexpr)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because accessing a raw array using `[]` does not perform bounds check. Using `std::array` could be a good alternative; you can access elements at a particular index using the `.at()` method.