# What does size_t mean in c++?

Tags: c++

C function `void *__cdecl malloc(size_t _Size);` and C++ template class `template < class T, size_t N > class array;` both mention the type `size_t`.

`int *p = (int*)malloc(6*sizeof(int));` statement allocates a memory of 6*sizeof(int) bytes.

However, `array<int, 6*sizeof(int)> myArray;` statement allocates a memory of 6*sizeof(int)*sizeof(int) bytes.

I want to know if the first `size_t` have the same meaning with the second `size_t`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951519/when-to-use-stdsize-t and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131803/unsigned-int-vs-size-t pretty much cover it.

Comment: Type `size_t` itself does not speak to the significance of values of that type any more than type `int` speaks to the significance of `int`s.  `size_t` is wide enough to represent the size, in bytes, of any object, including array objects, but that does not in any way mean that `size_t` values must be such object sizes.

Comment: `std::size_t` is the type returned by `sizeof`.  It is defined in 7 header files.  More info: [std::size_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).