# C++ for-loop - size_type vs. size_t

Tags: c++, vector, for-loop, size-type

In the `C++ Primer` book, Chapter (3), there is the following for-loop that resets the elements in the vector to zero.

```
for (vector<int>::size_type ix = 0; ix ! = ivec.size(); ++ix)
ivec[ix] = 0;
```

Why is it using `vector<int>::size_type ix = 0`? Cannot we say `int ix = 0`? What is the benefit of using the first form on the the second?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The C++ Standard says,

> ```
>  size_type  |  unsigned integral type  |  a type that can represent the size of the largest object in the
> allocation model
> ```

Then it adds,

> Implementations of containers
>   described in this International
>   Standard are permitted to assume that
>   their Allocator template parameter
>   meets the following two additional
>   requirements beyond those in Table 32.
>
> - **The typedef members pointer, const_pointer, size_type, and
>     difference_type are
>     required to be T*,T const*, size_t, and ptrdiff_t, respectively**

So most likely, `size_type` is a typedef of `size_t`.

And the Standard really defines it as,

```
template <class T> 
class allocator 
{
   public:
       typedef size_t size_type;
       //.......
};
```

So the most important points to be noted are :

- `size_type` is `unsigned` integral, while `int` is **not** *necessarily* `unsigned`. :-)
- it can represent the largest index, because it's unsigned.

Comment: and when the reference states that the allocator's size_type needs to be size_t and after C++14 if the size() doesent fit in size_t then the program is ill-formed, than why to world we need either the size_t and the size_type? Maybe some unecessary confusion? (we know that C++ like it)

Comment: re "int is not necessarily unsigned" `int` is  *never* unsigned.

Answer (score 17):

Yes you can use `int`, but only the type `vector<int>::size_type` guarantees that its type can be used to index all vector elements.

It may or may not be the same size as `int`. Eg, when compiling for 64-bit Windows, `int` is 32-bit wide, whereas `vector<int>::size_type` will be 64-bit wide.

Instead of using the rather verbose `vector<int>::size_type`, you could use `std::size_t`, as the former is a typedef for the latter. However, if you ever happen to change the container type, then its `size_type` maybe a different type, and you may have to modify your code if it uses `std::size_t`.

Comment: more than that, size_type will probably never be int. It will generally be size_t (unsigned int).

Comment: Yes, I meant that it could be the same size as an int.

Comment: Can the size be of types other than `int` or `unsigned int`?

Comment: @Daniel Gehriger. When you say `when compiling for 64-bit Windows, int is 32-bit wide, whereas vector<int>::size_type will be 64-bit wide.', but aren't they at the end of type `int`. Where is the problem here? Thanks

Comment: Well yes, on a 64-bit platform, it will more likely be `unsigned long long`.

Comment: The size of `int` is implementation dependent. For VisualC++, for instance, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(VS.80).aspx. As you can see, `int` is 32-bit, but pointers are 64-bit. See also http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/31/363790.aspx

Comment: @Daniel: to be precise, `int` could have been `64` bits wide, but there is so much code around that relied on the `32` bits length (notably performing a number of bit-wise manipulations) that most compilers preferred to let it be `32` bits. It also saves some space.

Comment: @Mathhieu, yes I know. I referred to `int` as defined by VisualC++. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: *Instead of using the rather verbose vector<int>::size_type, you could use std::size_t, as the former is a typedef for the latte* is not true. It *may* be the same but there is no requirement.

Answer (score 9):

`vector<int>::size_type` is a type that is guaranteed to hold the size of the biggest `vector` you may have, and thus it's guaranteed to let you index all the elements of the `vector` (since indexes go from 0 to size-1); it is the type used for indexes and sizes in all the `vector` methods.

If you have very big arrays this may be actually relevant, since other integer types may overflow (and if they are `signed` types things can get quite strange); even if you won't ever get to arrays so big that this may matter, it's fundamentally a code cleanliness thing; moreover, your `ix` has the same type of `ivec.size()`, so you don't get warnings for comparing signed and unsigned integers.

**Background**: `vector<T>::size_type` is usually a `typedef` for `size_t` (I read somewhere that actually the standard <s>implicitly</s> imposes it to be `size_t` - **EDIT**: it's not implicit at all, see *@Nawaz*'s answer), which, in turn, is the return type of the `sizeof` operator. This implicitly says that it can hold the size for the biggest object usable in a C++ application, so it is surely (just) big enough to index arrays of any type.

Actually, I use `size_t` (defined in `<cstddef>`) as index also for C-style arrays, and I think it's good practice for exactly the same reasons.

---

By the way, you may also forget of the type used for indexes altogether and just go with iterators:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = ivec.begin(); it != ivec.end(); ++it)
    *it = 0;
```

or with iterators+`<algorithm>`:

```
std::fill(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), 0);
```

These two options work whatever container `ivec` is, so you don't have to change anything in the code if you decide to change container type.

With `vector` you can also use the `assign` method (as suggested in some other answer):

```
ivec.assign(ivec.size(), 0);
```

Comment: Do you use `size_t` or `std::size_t`? ;-)

Comment: `std::size_t`, there's an implicit `using namespace std;` at the top of this answer (but not in my code) `:P`

Comment: When you say `vector<int>::size_type is a type that is guaranteed to specify the size of the biggest vector you may have`, can you explain it further a bit? Thanks

Comment: @user588855: sorry it was poor wording, replace "specify" with "hold"; however, I meant that it's guaranteed that the type `size_type` can store the size (=number of items) of the biggest array you can actually allocate, so, whatever the size of your array is, you're sure that, iterating over it using `size_type` as index, you won't get any integer overflow problem.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `int`because `vector<int>::size_type` is an unsigned type, that is, vector indexes its elements with an unsigned type. `int` however is a signed type and mixing signed and unsigned types can lead to weird problems. (Although it would not be a problem for small n in your example.)

Note that I think it's clearer to just use `size_t` (as opposed to T::size_type) - less typing and should work on all implementations.

Note also that the for loop you posted:

```
for(size_t ix=0; ix != ivec.size(); ++ix) ...
```

would be better written as:

```
for(size_t i=0, e=ivec.size(); i!=e; ++ix) ...
```

-- no need to call size() every iteration.

Comment: Actually, I would be very surprised if the assembly code for the first version of your `for` loop was any more compact than the 2nd. The call to `vector<T>::size()` will be inlined.

Comment: @Fred: I'd agree in the general case. But for the templated `std::vector`, all code affecting the vector size is clearly visible to the compiler, as it has to specialize it for the element type. I quickly ran a test and, indeed, there isn't a difference.

Comment: @Fred: Oh yes, in that case it isn't the same of course. But I believe that @Martin's point was about optimization and my opinion is that this kind of optimization only makes code more difficult to read without actually affecting performance. If the algorithm demands it, then that's another issue.

Comment: @Fred: I believe we both agree. Note that the compiler doesn't have to assume anything about what `some_func` does with `v`. The call to `v.size()` can always be inlined as a load from the memory location where the vector size is stored. The compiler just can't use a register for it, which it can when using the OP's optimization.

Comment: @Daniel: I won't enter a discussion about the optimizer here. Suffice to say that the second form I posted is *my* recommended idiomatic use of a C++ for loop. I find it clear what's going on, and it also makes the intention clear that size certainly won't change during the for-loop.

Comment: @Martin: no problem - I didn't mean to offend anyone. I felt that, when applied to the OP's problem, this micro-optimization wasn't needed. @Fred: no, I know it's based on the difference of two pointers; again, once compiled, the assembly will be identical if it's clear to the compiler that `v.size()` cannot change.

Comment: @Daniel: No offense taken :-) - What I wanted to say was that I do not view this as a micro-optimization but rather as a coding-style I have adopted and use always.

Comment: @Martin: Great! I see the point. I do it myself. Like using pre-incrementing `++i`  when possible even for simple datatypes.