# What should be the index type when iterating over the elements of a vector?

Tags: c++, loops, types, indexing, stdvector

I usually iterate over a vector that way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {
    Element* e = myVector[i];
}
```

But then the compiler usually gives me this warning:

```
warning: C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
```

So if an `int` is not right, which type should the index be? vector::size() seems to be of a "size_type" type, but I'd rather use a more meaningful type. Any suggestion?

Comment: Instead of using indexes, consider using iterators.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `std::vector<T>::size_type`<sup>1</sup>. Its unsigned integral type. Its *usually* same as `size_t`.

To know the difference between `size_type`  and `size_t`, see this topic:

- [C++ for-loop - size_type vs. size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849678/c-for-loop-size-type-vs-size-t)

<sup>1. Similarly, you can use `std::string::size_type`, `std::list<T>::size_type`, `std::deque<T>::size_type`, `std::set<T>::size_type`, and so on. Almost all standard containers define a nested type called `size_type`.</sup>

---

One can argue that you should use *iterator* instead of *index*. But I also see that sometime iterator makes the for-loop very wide horizontally, see this :

```
for(std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
}
```

It doesn't look. It in fact irritates sometimes.  In such situations, some programmers prefers *index* over *iterator*.

In C++0x, *iterator* has been made more idiomatic. Now you can use *iterator* without making the syntax cumbersome:

```
for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{  
}
```

Or even better, using *range-based* for loop:

```
for(auto & item : v)
{
}
```

Comment: If you insert elements at the end of the vector, its iterators are invalidated, but indices are unaffected.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler gives the warning because your int is signed but size() returns an unsigned int of type size_t. You don't want this kind of mismatch because it can cause headaches if your int is negative. You can avoid all of this by using size_t.

Answer (score 0):

If you are *just* using it for iteration, then you might want to use:

```
    typedef std::vector<Element*> ElementContainer;
    ElementContainer myVector(3);

    for (ElementContainer::const_iterator cit = myVector.begin();cit != myVector.end(); ++cit)
    {
        Element* e = *cit;
    }
```

This has the advantage of being slightly more robust to changing from `vector<>` to another container.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `unsigned`. With `size_t` you never remember what the right header to include is, and with `vector<T>::size_type` you end up typing too much. For all practical purposes they are the same thing, just re`typedef`ed a dozen of times.

Comment: On a typical 64 bit machine, `std::size_t` and `unsigned` are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @David, what would be the different on a 64 bits machine? Could I run into any problem if I use `unsigned int` instead of `size_t`?

Comment: You'll run into problems using `unsigned int` if the number of items in the vector exceeds 4294967295. If you think your application might even come close to having a vector that is that big you will have known this well in advance. In most cases you will not have any problems using `unsigned int` instead of `std::size_t`.

Comment: -1 because all it takes to know which one is the best header to include std::size_t is a google search: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t and 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstddef