# what is the correct type for this loop?

Tags: c++

where RoomCentreNodeVectors is a vector of vectors of ints.
roomKills is a vector of ints and level.Nodes() returns a vector of Node objects. The Node object's Room() function returns and int.

```
for (std::vector<std::vector<int>>::size_type i = 0; i < level.RoomCentreNodeVectors().size(); i++)
{
    RoomKills.push_back(level.Nodes()[level.RoomCentreNodeVectors()[i][0]].Room());
}
```

or

```
for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < level.RoomCentreNodeVectors().size(); i++)
{
    RoomKills.push_back(level.Nodes()[level.RoomCentreNodeVectors()[i][0]].Room());
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just sticking to iterators?

Comment: Obviously, you need to refactor all this stuff into named variables. My eyes bleed.

Comment: Whichever one compiles, I guess!

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes because I haven't learnt about them yet I suppose. I thought this was right because.size() returns those sizes.

Comment: @VictorSorokin can you link me to some info about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate. See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849678/c-for-loop-size-type-vs-size-t

Comment: @SirYakalot yep, http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/

Comment: @VictorSorokin thanks. Also, what is it about the code which you dislike so much? Forgetting that this is clearly not the best method, if the size_type was a typedef for example, would that address the issues you have with it? or would there also be other things you change?

Comment: @SirYakalot I meant that code is hard to read because there are too long call chains per single line. I think if you have call chain with more than 2 calls, it's hard to read (unless you use some `fluent interface` pattern). Refactoring is for making code more readable and maintainable, not more "logically correct".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you should be using size_type of the type of vector that is being indexed into.  If RoomCentreNodeVectors() returns a vector of vector of int, then your first loop specifies the type correctly.  Most likely it will equate to size_t.

The rest of this is answering more than your question and you may ignore it if you wish.

First, typedefs will help make this easier to read.  For example

```
typedef std::vector<Node> NodeVec;
typedef std::vector<int> IntVec;
typedef std::vector<IntVec> IntVecVec;
for (IntVecVec::size_type i = 0; ...
```

Unless the value of RoomCentreNodeVectors() changes during this loop, I would certainly save the return value so that you don't have to make that function call every time.  This is especially true if the function returns a value rather than a reference type, because you'll be copying that vector twice every time through the loop.  And, as a R. Martinho Fernandes mentioned, you could use iterators as well, and avoid the whole size_type question:

```
const IntVecVec& nodeVecs = RoomCentreNodeVectors();
IntVecVec::const_iterator end = nodeVecs .end();
const NodeVec& nodes = level.Nodes(); // if Nodes() doesn't change during loop
for (IntVecVec::const_iterator iter = nodeVecs .begin(); iter != end; ++iter)
{
    const IntVec& vec = *iter;
    int j = vec[0];
    int room = nodes[j].Room();
    RoomKills.push_back(room);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, since the actual type of `size_type` doesn't depend on the template specialization. It's usually the same as `size_t`, which I suggest you use for better readability:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < level.RoomCentreNodeVectors().size(); i++)
{
    RoomKills.push_back(level.Nodes()[level.RoomCentreNodeVectors()[i][0]].Room());
}
```

If I saw your snippet in code, I would refactor it.

Comment: ah ok, but then why does it demand you specify a type for the vector? Is there any difference between the longer size_type and size_t?

Comment: @SirYakalot I don't think it's guaranteed to be the same but most probably is. You need to specify <int> because you can't use vector otherwise (or any template).

Comment: See also [size_t vs container::size_type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type) .  I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/920202) to be especially interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I would change this code to using iterators ... you can then, using the C++11 `auto` keyword do the following:

```
for(auto iter = begin(level.RoomCentreNodeVectors); iter != end(level.RoomCentreNodeVectors); iter++)
{
    RoomKills.push_back(level.Nodes()[(*iter)[0]].Room());
}
```

Comment: this doesn't address the question.

Comment: Why not?  He wanted to know what the type of the loop is, and we're using the `auto` keyword with iterators to allow the compiler to deduce that type rather than explicitly specifying it.

Comment: Ok... so what is the type of the loop (by which I understand the type of the iterator)?

Comment: The type for `iter`, without using the `auto` keyword, would be `std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator` ... using the `auto` keyword of course makes this much simpler code, and also more flexible since we are not explicitly stating types (i.e., if he changes something in the future with the vector container, he won't have to change the type for the iterator)

Comment: But it's not iterator in his question, it's size_type. See my point? You're posting new code, and answering his question based on your code. Also, this only applies to C++11

Comment: Okay, I do concede your point.  I still think this answer has some value though, but I'll agree to disagree if you feel differently. BTW, the OP is also using C++11 since he does not have a space between his template instantiation in the first code segment.  In other words `std::vector<std::vector<int>>::size_type` would not compile under C++03.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Right_angle_bracket as well as http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#brackets

Comment: But it compiles for me... I guess VS08 is overly-permissive.