# difference between size_type and int

Tags: c++, vector, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> student_marks(20);

    for (vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter marks for student #" << i+1 
            << ": " << flush;
        cin >> student_marks[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I read somewhere that it is better to use `size_type` in place of `int` . Does it really make a huge impact on the implementation and what are the positives of using `size_type` ?

Comment: `size_type` will be able to hold all indices and won't give a warning when you do `i < student_marks.size()`.

Comment: It is more important to use ``i < student_marks.size()`` as condition in the for loop, or, even better to use iterators: ``for (auto it = student_marks.begin(); it < student_marks.end(); ++it)``. You can then access the vector element as ``*it``, e.g. ``cin >> *it``.

Comment: @ChristianAichinger yeah I am reading about vectors , came across this toy example that's why I posted .

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ for-loop - size\_type vs. size\_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849678/c-for-loop-size-type-vs-size-t)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`vector<double>::size_type` is guaranteed to cover the full range of possible values of the size of a `vector<double>`. An `int` is not.

Note that `vector<double>::size_type` is usually the same as `std::size_t`, so in general it would be OK to use the latter. However, custom allocators can result in the a vector with a `size_type` different to `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 4):

`size_type` is an **unsigned** number. This means it cannot be negative. Which may sound a logical choice for container sizes, but in real life creates a lot of **problems**.

For example, when you substract one `size_type` from another, the result will silently be converted to a huge positive number if the second operand is greater than the first:

```
std::vector<double>::size_type size1 = v1.size();
std::vector<double>::size_type size2 = v2.size();
if ((size1 - size2) > 5) // dangerous if v2 is bigger than v1!
{
    // ...
}
```

And it often makes error checking impossible:

```
void f(std::vector<double>::size_type size)
{
    if (size < 0)
    {
        // error handling will never be reached    
    }
}

f(-1); // no error handling
```

It is for such problems that you usually prefer (signed) `int` to `unsigned` in your code, and it is unfortunate that standard library containers express their sizes as unsigned numbers. You will often want to convert (`static_cast`) sizes to signed numbers as soon as possible. In your example, it's fine to stay unsigned, because it's just the loop index, and casting to `int` first would be over-engineering IMO.

The good news is that you can often avoid `size_type` altogether by using **iterators**:

```
for (std::vector<double>::const_iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); ++iter)
{
    std::cout << *iter;
}
```

I invite you to have a look at [Signed and Unsigned Types in Interfaces](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/sep95.pdf) by Scott Meyers.

Finally, please note that this point of view is **not universally shared** by experienced C++ programmers. Searching for past discussions about this topic on the web (old Stackoverflow questions, comp.lang.c++ Usenet archive etc) will reveal different opinions.

Answer (score 3):

The positives of using `size_type`, as opposed to `size_t`, is just conformity. It pleases those who learn by rote and reason purely by association. They do like they see others like themselves do, and want to have that be perceived as “right”.

The `size_type` member is a customization point for the container’s size type. It comes from the allocator template parameter. With the default standard allocator it's just a synonym for `size_t`, i.e. these are, by default, *the same type*.

The problem with `int`, as opposed to the signed type `ptrdiff_t` (the result type for a pointer difference), is that `int` may not have sufficient range for a really huge vector on a 64-bit system.

The problem with `size_t` is that it can easily cause inadvertent use of modulo arithmetic in mixed type expressions. For example, the expression `std::string( "Hi!" ).length() < -7` will always yield `true`. Thus it's a bug-attractor, so `ptrdiff_t`, or just plain `int` when you're sure of the range, is very much objectively preferable (even though it may displease the aforementioned folks enormously  – there is still a very strong social pressure to use the objectively inferior solution).

In the standard library the unsigned type `size_t` is used for **historical reasons**.

In particular, on 16-bit systems memory was a very limited resource, and one had to use every little dirty trick to make use of absolutely all of it  –  for those small systems, in those days, it was well worth the risk of some wrap-around bugs etc. Today it isn't.

Comment: What happens if you do `size_type < signed int` - are you saying that the signed int doesn't get converted to unsigned, but if you did `size_t < signed int`, it would?

Comment: @GavinSmith: you can't compare types, as in your example, but you can compare instances/values. but, guessing at your intent, no `size_type` does not have any advantage over `size_t` here. with the default template arguments for standard library containers, `size_type` *is* `size_t`. I updated the answer to mention this. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Thank you for going into enough detail that I actually understand the reasoning and can make my own design decisions with confedence.

Comment: @PorkyBrain: You're welcome. Just be strongly aware of backward compatibility (which is what `size_t` is about), in all kinds of data processing! E.g., yesterday I learned that Microsoft Excel accepts the date of 29th February 1900, thereby introducing an off-by-1 error in its day count, just in order to be compatible with a bug in now archaic VisiCalc, which once was its main competitor. It's like that everywhere. To some degree. ;-)