# Vector index variable declaration (size_t or std::vector<DATATYPE>::size_type)

Tags: c++, vector, variable-declaration

What is the best practice for declaring a new variable for comparison with the size of a vector? which of the following should we favor (i.e. vector of doubles)?

1. `uint compareVar;`
2. `std::uint64_t compareVar;`
3. `std::size_t compareVar;`
4. `std::vector<double>::size_type compareVar;    // how is this different than size_t?`

and why?

Comment: `size_t` depends on the environment (32/64 bits, compiler, etc). And it's how the standard `vector::size` is implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one that you must use is `std::vector::size_type`. it is usually `std::size_t` but standard doesn't specify it. it is possible one implementation uses another type. You should use it whenever you want to refer to `std::vector` size.

`uint`, `uint64_t` and even `size_t` must not be used because in every implementation and platform the underlying vector implementation may use different types.

Comment: Yes, it is, but there is no guarantee that `std::vector::size_type` is always equal to `size_t`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849780/9304999

Answer (score 1):

If you need an equality or ordinal comparison only, the best type would be the one used by vector's implementation, meaning

```
std::vector<MyType>::size_type compareVar
```

This guarantees that the type you use matches the type of vector's implementation regardless of the platform.

Note that since the type is unsigned, computing the difference between vector's size and `compareVar` would require some caution to avoid incorrect results when subtracting a larger value from a smaller one.

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't `size_t` do the same? isn't it platform independent as well?

Comment: @Bu_ali `size_t` is indeed platform-independent, but `std::vector`'s implementation is under no obligation to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In order of "goodness": 4 3 1 2.

`std::vector::size_type` is an implementation defined unsigned integer type that is guaranteed to be able to index all elements in any vector. It is good to use this, because it is guaranteed to be at least as large as is needed in all cases, but is not required to be any larger than that.

`std::size_t` is an implementation defined unsigned integer type that is guaranteed to be able to represent the size of any object. `std::vector::size_type` is typically same as this, but that is not guaranteed in theory.

`uint` There is no such type in C++, but I assume that you mean `unsigned`. This is not guaranteed to be able to represent all indices of a vector. In fact, on 64 bit systems which are ubiquitous, largest representable value of `unsigned` is often much much less than largest possible vector. Still, if you know that the upper limit is much less in your program, then using this is probably fine... as long as that assumption never changes.

`std::uint64_t` is an unsigned type that is not guaranteed to exist on all systems, and is not guaranteed to be sufficiently large to represent all indexes of a vector, although it is likely be sufficient on 64 bit systems and those with even smaller address space, which essentially covers nearly all computers at the moment.