# How to iterate through characters in each string in a vector of strings?

Tags: c++, string, vector

Trying to iterate through every character in each string from a vector and verify all characters are 'O' or '.'

```cpp
//read file, put it in vector, and handle some errors
string line;
vector<string> currentgen; 
while (getline(input_stream, line)) {
    currentgen.push_back(line);
}

//iterate through every character in each string, 
//and verify all characters are 'O' or '.' 
for(int i = 0; i < currentgen.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < i.length(); j++){
        if(currentgen[i][j] != 'O' || currentgen[i][j] != '.'){
        cerr << program_name << ": Bad Character in: "<<file_name<< "\n";
        exit(3)
        }
    }
}
```

This is giving an error:

```
error: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'}
   for(int i = 0; i < currentgen.size(); i++){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

1. You used `||` where you should have used `&&`; obviously, a character is always not equal to one of `'O'` or `'.'`, so the condition is always true as written; you want:

   ```
        if(currentgen[i][j] != 'O' && currentgen[i][j] != '.'){
                                   ^^ changed
   ```
2. There's also a missing semi-colon after `exit(3)`
3. You've got warnings turned up, and it's angry you used an `int` as your iteration variable; making it a `size_t` would likely fix the error (though technically, [the correct change is making it `vector<string>::size_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4849678/364696)). A better solution would be to let C++ handle iteration with a for-each loop like:

   ```
    for(const auto& str : currentgen){
   ```

   then avoiding indexing for that loop in the first place.

Comment: thank you so much! 
this was the ending working result!
```
for(const auto& str : currentgen){
  for(const auto& j : str){
   if(j != 'O' && j != '.'){
   cerr << program_name << ": Bad Character in: "<<file_name<< "\n";
   exit(3);
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

From c++20, you can iterate through every character in a vector of strings like this:

```
for(char c : currentgen | std::views::join | std::views::join)
{   
  // ...
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3xvsfM).

---

Of course, you're better off using an algorithm instead of iterating through characters manually:

```
auto O_or_dot = [](char c) { return c == 'O' || c == '.'; };

if (not std::ranges::all_of(currentgen 
                            | std::views::join 
                            | std::views::join, O_or_dot))
  cerr << program_name << ": Bad Character in: "<<file_name<< "\n";
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/416Kx8).

Comment: Both of your demo links do not compile

Comment: @A_P Thanks for the heads up. Probably a bug that was recently introduced in trunk. I've edited the demos to use gcc10.2 instead.