# How do all the different size types relate to each other?

Tags: c++, size-type

Currently I have a scenario where I want to check whether writing a given string to a filestream will grow the file beyond a given size (this is used for logfile rotation). Now, `std::ofstream::tellp()` returns a `streampos`, but `std::string::size()` returns a `size_t`. The effect is, that this does not work:

```
out_stream.tellp() + string.size() < limit
```

because apparently there is an ambiguous overload of `operator +` for these types. This leads me to two questions:

1. How can I resolve the above ambiguity?
2. How do all the different types (`size_t`, `streamsize`, `streampos`, `streamoff`) relate to each other? When can they be safely converted, and what are possible pitfalls. I am generally confused about these types. All I know is that they are implementation dependent, and that they make certain guarantees (e.g. `size_t` is always large enough to hold the size of the larges object that would fit into memory on the architecture for which the application was compiled), but what are the guarantees concerning interoperability of these types (see example above, or comparing a `streamsize` to a `size_t`)?

Comment: `std::string::size()` returns an `std::string::size_type`, which isn't guaranteed to be a `size_t`.

Comment: @Etienne: Thanks for clarifying that. Unfortunately, this only makes things more complicated.

Comment: @Etienne: for most people it is though (ie when no custom allocator is in use): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to convert the result from tellp to a `std::string::size_type` by casting.

`static_cast<std::string::size_type>(out_stream.tellp()) + string.size() < limit`

EDIT: This is safe because your stream offset will never be negative and will safely convert to an unsigned value.

Comment: I know that this is possible, but is it safe?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y Since it's a static_cast (not reinterpret), if the conversion doesn't make sense the compiler will complain. Should be safe.

Comment: `std::string::size_type` is unsigned, `std::streampos` isn't. But it should be safe.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: This is not safe at all without some bounds checking, or at least some static assertions about the sizes. It is very possible for `streamoff` to be 64 bits and `size_t` to be 32 bits. (In fact this is exactly what you get on a 32-bit POSIX system when you define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, a very common compilation mode not so long ago.)

Answer (score 3):

The real question is: what is the type of limit?  The usual way of
testing if there is still room is usually:
    limit - out_stream.tellp() >= string.size()
But you have to ensure that limit has a type from which
out_stream.tellp() can be subtracted.

In theory, streampos isn't convertable nor comparable to an integral
type, or that, converted to an integral type, it gives significant
information.  And it needed support subtraction, or comparison, for that
matter.  In practice, I don't think you have to worry too much about the
conversion to an integral type existing, and being monotonic (although
perhaps on some exotic mainframe...).  But you can't be sure that
arithmetic with it will work, so I'd probably prefer converting it
explicitly to a streamsize (which is guaranteed to be a signed integral
type).  (Regardless of how you approach the problem, you'll have to deal
with the fact that string.size() returns a size_t, which is required to
be unsigned, whereas streamsize is required to be signed.)

With regards to your second question:
    size_t is a typedef to an unsigned integral type, large enough to
        specify the size of any possible object,
    streamsize is a typedef to a signed integral type, large enough to
        specify the size of an "object" in a stream,
    streamoff is a typedef to an integral type capable of specifying
        the position of a byte in a file, and 
    streampos is a typedef to fpos, where
        something is a type which can be used to maintain the state in
        the case of a multibyte stream.
The standard makes very few requirements concerning the relationships
between them (and some of the few it makes are mathematically impossible
to realize), so you're pretty much on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the standard says that `streamsize` is implementation-specific, so no help there. For a practical answer, you can check the headers where these are `typedef`ed.

Considering that `size_t` might be 4 bytes while your application *could* conceivably operate on a stream of more than 4GB length, I believe that you should cast to a known-good-size type for interoperating for an airtight solution.

Of course, if you know (maybe with a compile-time assertion) that `size_t` or `streamsize` is 8 bytes long, you can use that type directly. If you have a stream whose length doesn't fit in 8 bytes, you have more serious problems than casting to the right type.

Comment: Checking the typedefs does not really help me, because I want portable code. The question is, is there any guarantee that for instance a `streamsize` always fits into a `size_t`?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Not one that I can find. But using a suitable compile-time assertion will not let you compile if it doesn't fit, so you 're covered. For maximum portability, use your own `typedef`. Then you can use `#ifdef` to detect the platform/compiler and `#include` a header with a suitable definition for the `typedef`, much like any large portable C++ library does.

Answer (score 0):

If you have big sizes, isn't **unsigned long long** the best you can get. If that isn't big enough, what else is?