# C++ : Is size_t a companion type just like size_type?

Tags: c++

Is size_t a companion type like size_type? What don't they standardize the companion type name when comes to size type - meaning just size_type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type

Comment: "Companion" type?

Comment: I think this question has the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type

Comment: well in C++ primer by Lipmann, the size_type for container is a companion type - at least that's what the author calls it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what a companion type is. But `size_t` is a standard type in C, and `std::size_t` is a standard type in C++ as well. Other things in the language depend on this type, like the result of `sizeof` or the argument to `new[]`.

The only place the standard talks about `size_type` is whitin containers. It's specified to be among other things the type of value returned by `size()`. It's usually defined in terms of the `allocator::size_type`, which is usually -but does not have to be- `std::size_t`.

Comment: For instance, a custom allocator can allocate memory on a server on the internet, in which case, `pointer`, `ptrdiff_t`, and `size_type` will probably be classes with complex logic.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is not a companion type. For one thing, it's been around long before the very notion of companion types existed. Also, it's a part of C standard where the companion types can't exist.