# String "companion types"

Tags: c++, string

A book talks about `string::size_type` (which is the return type of the `string.size()` function of the `std::string` class).

I don't understand what are these "companion types". Could someone give me a detailed explanation of what they are? How can we access them? How can we create them in a class? I heard they are some kind of type alias, how? I can't find any of these information on the net.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ : Is size\_t a companion type just like size\_type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921601/c-is-size-t-a-companion-type-just-like-size-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Companion types` is likely just a figurative way to mention `member types` i.e. types declared within another type

For instance [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) has a bunch of them along with `size_type`

You are right, they are type aliases created with `typedef` or `using` (since c++11)

For example `foo` has two `companion` types in it but only one is accessible to users due to visibility

```
class foo
{
public:
    using bar = int;
private:
    struct internal { /* impl */};
    ...
    typedef internal baz;
}
```

Anyone can now instantiate variables of `foo::bar` type and it also lets author of `foo` (or `std::string`) to change member types later without you rewriting your code as long as you use them consistently

Comment: I'm not sure, lets see what author says

Comment: Why would I want to use foo::bar instead of int?

Comment: @gigi because you don't really know it is `int` unless you look inside foo implementation, in case of `std::string::size_type` you dont really need to know what it alises as long as you use it consistently

Comment: @gigi it also lets author of foo and string to change it later without you rewriting your code

Comment: Also, it is written that "these companion types make it possible to use the library types in a machine-independent manner." What does that mean?

Comment: Same what I meant, if you use `std::string::size_type` it may be defined/aliased to 16 bits on one platform and 32 or 64 bits on another but you dont even need to know that. I.e can just recompile your code and everything would work as expected

Answer (score 4):

The `std::string` type - along with the other sequence containers - have a bunch of associated types. For example, there's `string::iterator`, a type that can iterate over characters from a string.

The type `string::size_type` is some type that's capable of holding the size of a string. You can use it by writing something like this:

```
string::size_type size = myString.size(); // Or something else
```

It's uncommon to see people actually use this type in routine programming practice. Most folks just use `size_t` or `auto` here.

The reason the `string::size_type` type is there is so that template functions that work on sequence containers can take in a template argument and then extract useful information from it, like this:

```
template <typename Sequence> void doSomething(const Sequence& seq) {
    typename Sequence::size_type size = seq.size();
    ...
}
```

You're probably not going to be doing things like that any time soon, though, so feel free to just use `size_t` or something like it.