# overload subscript operator does not return pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, c++11, operator-overloading

In my class, I have a member variable `std::vector<node*>` children
I want to overload the subscript operator so that I can easily index one of the nodes.

---

Here is my class deceleration for that function:

```
node* operator[](int index);
```

---

Here is my class definition for that function:

```
node* class_name::operator[](int index){

    return children[index];
}
```

---

However, this function does not seem to return a pointer as I had hoped.
Here is the function that is giving me trouble:

```
void Print_Tree(node* nptr, unsigned int & depth){

    if (NULL == nptr) {
        return;
    }
      //node display code

    for (int i = 0; i < nptr->Number_Of_Children(); ++i){
        Print_Tree(nptr[i],depth+1); //<- Problem Here!
    }
     //node display code

    return;
}
```

---

The error I get is:

> error: cannot convert ‘node’ to ‘node*’ on the recursive call

I don't understand why it gives me back a node when I want a pointer to a node.
Is there something wrong with my overloaded function?
I tried dereferencing the node in the recursive call:

```
Print_Tree(*nptr[i],depth+1);  
Print_Tree(*(nptr[i]),depth+1);
Print_Tree(nptr->[i],depth+1);
```

to no avail!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(*nptr)[i]` should do the trick. The problem is that you defined `operator[]` to work on `node` class, not on *pointer to* `node`. When you say `nptr[i]` you're calling the built-in `operator[]`.

Comment: Oh! very obvious now. thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your are looking for the problem in the right place, but the syntax in your three correction attempts is still slightly wrong.

`nptr` is a pointer to a `Node` object, so you cannot apply the index operator directly (if you do, the compiler will assume it points to the beginning of a `Node` array and jump to the ith entry).

Instead you need to first dereference the pointer, and then apply the index operator. Use parentheses to determine the order of this:

```
Print_Tree((*nptr)[i],depth+1);
```

---

On a separate note, your using `int` as the data type for the index into the vector is slightly incorrect. Better use `std::size_t` or `std::vector<Node*>::size_type`.

---

Furthermore, given that this question is tagged [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), I should point out that the correct way to refer to the null pointer is `nullptr`, not `NULL`.

Comment: It's not 'slightly incorrect' to use `int`. You can advocate `std::size_t` if you want, but you're selling `int` short.

Comment: @LucDanton What do you mean by "selling int short"?

Comment: @LucDanton `std::vector<>::operator[]` expects `std::vector<>::size_type`, so that should be used.

Comment: Signed vs unsigned types is an old debate very prone to flamewars. I'd rather not bring it up, but at the same time I'd rather not let anyone get the impression using `std::size_t`/`size_type` is the automatically correct thing to do. `int` or `std::ptrdiff_t`/`difference_type` certainly have their merits. I'm leaving it at that.

Comment: oh! syntax mistake.  That makes sense now- I can see why.  Use nullptr since it's safer. understood. this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type says that container::size_type is better for portability, but I've never even heard of std::ptrdiff_t/difference_type.  This is just a minor issue in my code, but something to look into. thanks guys.

Comment: On my system at least, INT_MAX is larger than std:vector::max_size(). I just habitually use size_t for iterations to silence compiler warnings about signed/unsigned comparison.

Comment: I am aware of the flamewars, but just to be clear: I recommend `size_type` over `int` not because I favour `unsigned` over `signed` (in which case it would be a matter of personal preference, and I wouldn't have called your code _slightly incorrect_). I recommend it because you are using `std::vector`, and the data type it expects is defined by the Standard. Deliberately using a different data type can get you into trouble due to automatic type conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is indeed legal to have `operator[]` return a pointer, it is better design (and fits expectations from standard classes) to return a reference instead. You can then take the address of that reference as follows:

```
node& class_name::operator[](int index){
    return *(children[index]);
}
```

and then use it as:

```
Print_Tree(&(*nptr)[i],depth+1);
```