# Choosing between size_t and container::size_type in compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, type-traits, size-type

I was thinking to be more pedantic in choosing data type in a block of code where I would need to choose between <strike>`size_type`</strike> `size_t` in general or `container::size_type` for container types. My problem is that if I have the following block of code, I don't know how to do it. Can anybody there help?

```
template<typename some_container>
int func(some_container& input)
{
    //Some code...
    //...
    decltype(input.size()) variable_x; //Choose this if defined,
    size_t                 variable_x; //otherwise choose this
    //... Some more code...
}
```

In this case `some_container` may be a *custom container* and does not provide `size()` function. What led me to this thinking was reading the difference between `size_t` and `container::size_type` at [size_t vs container::size_type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type). I also read [Determine if a type is an STL container at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407367/determine-if-a-type-is-an-stl-container-at-compile-time), but the approach feels a bit heavy-handed for my situation.

Comment: You have `size_type` and `size_t` the wrong way around in the question. ITYM "`size_t` in general or `container::size_type` for container types".

Comment: `auto` comes handy here: `auto size = input.size()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is one way to determine if a `class` contains a type (e.g. `size_type`) or not:

```
template <typename T> 
struct Has_size_type
{
  typedef char (&yes)[2];

  template <typename C> static yes test(typename C::size_type*);
  template <typename> static char test(...);

  static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

And following is the way to choose between 2 types:

```
template<bool> struct Bool;
template<typename T, typename = Bool<true> >
struct Set { typedef size_type type; };
template<typename T>
struct Set<T,Bool<Has_size_type<T>::value> > { typedef typename T::size_type type; };
```

**Edit start**: Here is another simpler approach:

```
template<typename T>
struct void_ { typedef void type; };

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct Set 
{ typedef size_type type; };

template<typename T>
struct Set<T,typename void_<typename T::size_type>::type>
{ typedef typename T::size_type type; };
```

**Edit end**.

So finally, use as below:

```
template<typename some_container>
int func(some_container& input)
{
  typedef typename Set<some_container>::type type;
}
```

So now `type` is either `size_type` or `some_container::size_type`, if it has that.

Comment: Why is your traits class called `Set`? That's (a) probably the single most ambiguous word in the English language, and (b) only one bit different from a completely unrelated name in `std::` ;-p

Comment: @SteveJessop, wrote it that way to convey 'meaningful' English sentence: `Set Some Container type!` :). I forgot for a moment that `std::set` also exists (I always wonder that why it's named so). Name for `Set` can be anything, ... author's choice!

Comment: @iammilind `std::set` is named so because it's a set.

Comment: As I wrote to Matthieu's code alreayd, I'll need to work on this later today (sans unforseeable obstructions). But I'll come back later.

Comment: Really difficult to decide between this and Matthieu's version, but I'll go with this one, if not by any other reason than being first and prodiving a link to code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You are on the right way using `decltype`, the trick is to use SFINAE which is easily done using either template classes or functions overloads. I will show the function way since it's so easy in C++11:

```
// One helper per size_type source
template <typename T>
auto size_type_alt(T const& t) -> decltype(t.size());

auto size_type_alt(...) -> std::size_t;

// The switch between helpers
template <typename T>
auto size_type_switch() -> decltype(size_type_alt(std::declval<T>{}));

// And syntactic sugar
template <typename T>
using size_type = decltype(size_type_switch<T>());
```

Usage:

```
template <typename T>
void some_algorithm(T const& t) {
    size_type<T> const size = 0;
    // ...
}
```

*Note: the switch and sugar coating layer could be blended together, however I thought you might appreciate seeing the steps separately.*

Comment: I'll need to work on this later on evening. This looks short and concise, but hey, I'm (re-)learning C++. :-) I've to read through iammilind's code too. And yes, I do appreciate steps in separate -- and the hint they could be blended together.

Comment: @Veksi: a friendly advice: take your time in assimilating things, and don't use things you are not comfortable with in production code ;)

Comment: This is hobby code, luckily. But it looks like duplication due to reasons like this creep on often, so one has to practise. By they way, that "auto size_type_alt(...) -> std::size_t" probably won't on Visual Studio 2012, I think. Hmm, I need to add that as a tag.

Answer (score 2):

If it does not have a `size_type` then it is not a container. Period.

The standard requires that all containers shall define a type named `size_type`. From N3337, 23.2.1 General container requirements [container.requirements.general]:

> **Expression:** `X::size_type`
>   **Return type:** unsigned integer type
>   **Assertion:** `size_type` can represent any non-negative value of
>   `difference_type`
>   **Complexity:** compile time

So your code can look simply as:

```
typename some_container::size_type variable_x;
```

Comment: What if `some_container` is a custom container which may or may not contain the `size_type`

Comment: @iammilind: custom types are not containers if they do not satisfy the container requirements. For example they may not work with the standard library container adapters, etc... In other words, container is, by definition, a type that satisfies the container requirements.

Comment: @iammilind: even some types from the standard library that look like containers (basic_string) are not actually containers, since they do not satisfy all the requirements (swap invalidates iterators, assumes PODs).

Comment: And if the questioner is using the word "container" to mean "something that satisfies requirements of my own definition, less than the standard Container requirements", then he has a few options. The most obvious is to add `size_type` to the requirements, but if that's not possible for legacy reasons then iammilind's SFINAE approach can test. The risk with that (and with implicit interfaces in general) is that if `size_type` isn't part of the defined interface of the type `some_container`, then who's to say the implementer of one of these types won't use the name for something unrelated?

Comment: I should probably say, the risk with *under-documented* implicit interfaces in general ;-). If the documentation were to say something like, "if `some_container::size` is defined then it must return an unsigned integer type large enough to hold the count of elements in any instance -- but it need not be defined if `std::size_t` satisfies that condition", then that would accurately reflect the implicit interface defined by the code.

Comment: It is as Steve Jessop writes, it's just some class that I'm calling "container". Perhaps a poorly chosen word in this context. The larger issue besides learning is that there's a lot of code around that doesn't adhere to the standard guidelines, but provides something to the effect and I would like to know how to "interchange" some blocks of code without duplicating code that much.

Comment: @Veksi: the most robust way is to write a wrapper (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for each miscellaneous class that is itself a standard Container. Or at least, that implements the subset of the Container requirements that you want to use. That way, you cope with the non-standardness of each type in one place, instead of in every function that uses them. With that design, you can if you want write templated wrappers that operate on multiple types, by detecting what they can like iammalind's answer. Also look at `boost::enable_if` / `std::enable_if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can and you should use `typename some_container::size_type` for this, even most STL compilers typedef `size_type` as `size_t` but as you say using this technique you can support custom containers

Answer (score 0):

Using @[Matthieu M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147192/)'s answer as a starting point, I use SFINAE to determine if T::size_type exists, rather than checking for `size()`. Very similar, just avoids the `auto`:

```
/** Fails if T::size_type isn't defined. */ 
template <class T>
typename T::size_type SizeType(const T &&t);

/** Fallback to a known size. */
template <class T>
std::size_t SizeType(const T &t);

...

using size_type = decltype(SizeType<T>(std::declval<T>()));
```

Like Matthieu did as well, the parameters to the methods must be different in this case to avoid ambiguity.