# Should I use size_type in my code

Tags: c++

I have a set of containers of different types, each of which is associated with a string id. The following function should print the id if the associated container is not empty.

If I want to pass the size of a std::vector to a function, should I pass it as a size_type object? Like this:

```
void printIfNotEmpty(const std::string& id, size_type sizeOfContainer)
{
   if(sizeOfContainer)
   {
     output << id << " is not empty";
   }
   else
   {
     output << id << " is empty";
   }
}
```

If so, in what namespace is size_type? How do I included its definition in my code?

Perhaps this is a solution:

```
template<class T>
void printIfNotEmpty(const std::string& id, const T& container)
{
  if(container.size())
  {
     output << id << " is not empty";
  }
  else
  {
     output << id << " is empty";
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a member typedef: `std::vector<T>::size_type`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass size of a string?

Comment: @billz No, another container

Comment: Why would you pass the size? You can get it from the passed vector or string.

Comment: @juanchopanza If I have different container types. For example, if I want my function above to work for std::vector<Foo> and std::vector<Baz>.

Comment: You still would not need to pass the size as a separate parameter.

Comment: @juanchopanza Not if I pass a ref to the vector, but then I need to template my class so it can handle a vector<A> and vector<B> etc. I taught it might be possible to just send the size irrespective of the vector type.

Comment: Maybe you could write some code to illustrate what you mean? I can't make any sense out of it.

Comment: @juanchopanza Added above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a weird interface, since

```
printIfNotEmpty("Baz", 37);
```

doesn't make much sense.

If you're really interested in the state of a different container, pass it as a parameter.
If you want to handle different types of containers, use a template.

```
template<typename T>
void printIfNotEmpty(const std::string& name, const std::vector<T>& collection)
{
    if (!collection.empty())
    // ...
}
```

or even more general

```
template<typename Collection>
void printIfNotEmpty(const std::string& name, const Collection& collection)
{
    if (!collection.empty())
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> should I pass it as a size_type object?

That's the most portable thing to do. (By the way, it's not an "object" in the sense of being a class type; it's an unsigned integer type, large enough to represent the size of any vector).

If you know that it's a vector with a standard allocator, and that's not likely to change in the future, then it might be less verbose to use `std::size_t` instead.

(Of course, in this simple example, it would make more sense to pass a boolean flag, or to remove the conditional and make the caller responsible for deciding whether to call the function; but I'm assuming that it's intended to represent more complex situations where it does make sense to pass a size around).

> If so, in what namespace is size_type?

Each of the standard containers (and any other container that's designed to meet the standard container requirements) defines it as a nested type.

> How do I included its definition in my code?

The definition is in `<vector>`; you must qualify it as `std::vector<whatever>::size_type`.

`std::size_t` is defined in `<cstddef>`.

Answer (score 2):

`size_type` is in `std` and, by the way, is not an object. And yes, you ought to use it for portability. For example, in Win64, if you use an `int` you'll get conversion warnings as `size_type` is larger than an `int` on that platform.

But before delving much deeper, see ['size_t' vs 'container::size_type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type).

Comment: Under the namespace std I have size_t but not size_type. What gives?

Comment: @Baz, I've appended an article link to my answer: well worth reading. Note though as juanchopanza states in the question comments, why do you need to pass the size? I've never had to do that. I'd pass a constant reference to the data container instead.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I got the size is not the size of the string, so if you just need to do what your code does you can do something like this:

```
void printIfNotEmpty(const std::string& name, bool empty) {
  if(!empty) {
    output << name;
  }
}
```

and call it:

```
printIfNotEmpty(a_string, a_vector.empty());
```

However for handling sizes I usually use a generic `size_t` type which is an unsigned integer type which size depends on the platform. Implicit type conversions are fine here so you don't have to overload the code with declarations like `std::vector<T>::size_type` which are often just a typedef for size_t.

Answer (score -1):

No you need to pass `std::vector<T>::size_type` where `T` is the type of your object.

For the second question, `size_type` is a `typedef` ( "aliases" for variable type) and it is namespace'd in the vector container class.