# vector<double>::size_type versus alternatives

Tags: c++

My background is mostly in R, SAS, and VBA, and I'm trying to learn some C++. I've picked "Accelerated C++" (Koenig, Moo) as one of my first books on the subject. My theoretical background in comp. sci. is admittedly not the most robust, which perhaps explains why I'm confused by points like these.

I have a question about a piece of code similar to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

   double input;
   std::vector<double> example_vector;

   while (std::cin >> input) {
      example_vector.push_back(input);
   } 

   std::vector<double>::size_type vector_size;
   vector_size = example_vector.size();

   return 0;
}
```

As I understand it, `vector_size` is "large enough" to hold the size of `example_vector`, no matter how large `example_vector` might be. I'm not sure I understand what this means: is `vector_size` (in this case) capable of representing an integer larger than, say, `long long x;`, so that `std::cout << vector_size;` would print a value that's different from `std::cout << x;`? How/why?

Comment: If you can use C++11 features, you can rely on `auto`: `auto vector_size = example_vector.size();`. I think it's unlikely that `vector::size_type` is something different than `std::size_t` in most implementations, but as it's not guaranteed, you can use the typedef ("paranoid mode").

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type

Comment: "As I understand it, vector_size is "large enough" to hold the size of example_vector, no matter how large example_vector might be" - That's not really true. Check out [`vector::max_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size). `vector::max_size()` returns `numeric_limits<size_type>::max()`, so if you use `std::uint8_t ` as `vector::size_type`, `vector::max_size()` will be `256`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this question boils down to is that the standard does not mandate what actual type is returned by the `vector<T>::size()` method. Different implementations may make different choices.

So, if you wish to assign the value returned by a call to `size()` to a variable, what type should you use for that variable? In order to write code that is portable across different implementations, you need a way to name that type, recognising the fact that different implementations of the standard library may use different types.

The answer is that `vector<T>` provides the type that you should use. It is

```
vector<T>::size_type
```

One thing that you do need to understand, and get used to, with C++, is that the standard does need to cater for significant variation between different implementations.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So, is it correct to think of it as a type in the same sense `double` is a type?

Comment: Indeed, size_type is a type

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<T>::size_type` is exactly what the standard implies, the type currently used by your implementation to allow storing the size.

Historically architectures have changed, requiring code parsers, retesting and other basic wastes of time.  By following the standards, your code will work on any complient platform, now and in the future.

So your code can work on 16bit archetectures and theoretically 256bit architectures at such time as they are supported.

So, while you are most likely only going to see it as `size_t` if you change platforms, you don't have to worry. And more importantly, whoever is maintaining your code doesn't have to either.

Answer (score -1):

In the vector class (and many others) they have a typedef:

```
typedef **implementation_defined** size_type;
```

A "size_type" may or may not use size_t. <del>That said, size_t is always large enough to cover all your memory (32 bits or 64 bit as might be.)</del> Note that it is likely that size_t will always be large enough to cover all your memory (at least as long as you program on your desktop computer), but that is not guaranteed.

Additionally, to know the size of a variable, and thus how much it can hold, you use sizeof.

So this would give you the actual size of the size_type type:

```
std::cout << sizeof(std::vector<double>::size_type) << std::endl;
```

which is going to be 4 or 8 depending on your processor and compiler. The maximum size is defined as 2 power that sizeof x 8 (i.e. 2 power 32 or 2 power 64.)

Comment: -1. Your implementation may have such a typedef, but just because that's what you see does not mean that that is what you will see in every implementation. The standard is very clear here: The typedef is `typedef **implementation defined** size_type`. In other words, `std::vector<T>::size_type` is implementation defined. It does not have to be `std::size_t`.

Comment: I said they have a typedef, it is likely to be size_t, but I did not say it would be. Actually, I explain that you wouldn't know unless you use sizeof() to determine the size of the type.

Comment: Your lead sentence says "*they have a typedef:* `typedef size_t size_t;`" That sentence leaves no wriggle room for an implementation that only supports vectors of 32768 elements or less. Change your `size_t` to implementation defined and I'll retract my down vote.

Comment: `size_t is always large enough to cover all your memory` false, -1.

Comment: @BillyONeal, do you know of operating systems that offer a size_t that is too small?

Comment: @Alexis: Yes; any PIC. Even if I wasn't aware of any; the standard makes no such guarantees.

Comment: @BillyONeal, I guess that makes sense. When I played with 6502 processors, I could not access all the memory with a pointer... (16 bit pointers allow only 64Kb, so if you have 386Kb...)