# Overflow in size parameter when declaring a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, overflow

```
int n = INT_MAX;
vector<int> v (n*n);
```

Will this result in a vector v of length n^2 or will overflow occur?

Comment: Undefined behavior will occur.

Comment: Would  vector<int> v ((long)(n*n))  work instead?

Comment: If you have 7.37869762948382 * 10^19 Bytes of RAM...

Comment: No, `n*n` results in signed integer overflow which by definition is undefined behavior. Your code is not guaranteed to work. Try it with `unsigned n = UINT_MAX` and overflow is then going to happen.

Comment: I should have been more clear with what I wanted out of this question. I was actually wondering whether if you had some int  n > sqrt(INT_MAX)  and declared v as above, v would be constructed with the desired size. I.e. would int multiplication be performed, or a more accommodating multiplication? Obviously I don't have 10000000000GB of RAM, Baum mit Augen. No one does, but actually I don't see that as a problem with the question. It's a question regarding the syntax and behavior of C++, so thank you 0x499602D2 for getting my point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit for vector size defined by [`vector::max_size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/max_size/) and you are above it.

For inherent limits related to the type of the size, see this [exising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type) contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
std::vector<int> v(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max());
```

or

```
std::vector<int> v(std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max());
```

Although there are no guarantees that your platform can allocate memory for an array of `int` large enough to hold that many items.

Comment: I can't see any problems with a vector of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 integers.