# shorter notation for size_type in std::vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, size

When iterating over a `std::vector`, I've always declared the index variable to be of `size_type` as in

```cpp
std::vector<someReallyLengthy<TypeWith,SubTypes>> a(5);
for (std::vector<someReallyLengthy<TypeWith,SubTypes>>::size_type k = 0; k < a.size(); k++) {
  // do something with a[k]
}
```

I'm wondering if in C++11 (or later) there's a shorthand-notation for the `size_type` here.

(`auto` won't work since it can't deduct from `0` which type it targets.)

Comment: `decltype(a.size())`. BTW, `auto` would deduce `int` from `0`.

Comment: Do you really need k, or a for range is enough ?

Comment: Sometimes I do need `k`. Good catch, though!

Comment: FYI: You can do `for (auto k = 0 * a.size(), k < a.size(); k++)`. The compiler (is expected to) optimizes the multiplication away and this line becomes equivalent to OP's. This trick doesn't please to everybody because it obfuscates the code. For this reason I decided to not make this an answer. Just be aware in case you find this out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use range-loop:

```
for (/*const*/ auto& el : a){
 //do something with el
}
```

according to this answer:['size_t' vs 'container::size_type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918567/size-t-vs-containersize-type) , `size_t` and `container::size_type` are equivilant for standard STL containers, so you can also use regular `size_t`

```
for (size_t i = 0; i<a.size();i++){
 //do something with a[i]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `decltype`:

```
for (decltype(a)::size_type k = 0; k < a.size(); k++) {
  // do something with a[k]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to TartanLlama's answer which addresses your question directly, note that in c++11 you're not constricted to iterate over the indices:

```
for(auto &v: e)
    // Do something with v
```

And, in case you really want the index, Nir Tzachar & I have [ported much of Python's range stuff](http://cpp_itertools_range.bitbucket.org/), so you can do:

```
for(auto &v: enumerate(e))
    // v has the index and value
```

(see [more](http://cpp_itertools_range.bitbucket.org/group__enumerate.html) on `enumerate` + examples.)

Answer (score 1):

This is my way

```
std::vector<someReallyLengthy<TypeWith,SubTypes>> a(5);
auto length = a.size();
for (decltype(length) k = 0; k < length; k++) {
  // do something with a[k]
}
```